# Insert in database

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I am using mybatis to insert the values using:

`Dao.xml`

```
<insert id="someId" parameterType="someBean" >
    INSERT ALL
     <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" >
    INTO table_name
               (ID,NAME)        
    VALUES
    (#{item.id},#{item.name})
   </foreach>   
   SELECT * FROM DUAL
</insert>
```

`Dao.java`

```
void someId(List<SomeBean> list);
```

List size passed is : 350

But while execution its raising an error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
 Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24335: cannot support more than 1000 columns
```

Database used here is oracle.

Comment: Does your target table *really* have just two columns?

Comment: @APC It has 20 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked "Does your target table really have just two columns?" and you said:

> It has 20 columns

I think this is the root of the error.

The INSERT ALL statement is subject to the Oracle limit that a SQL statement can only have 1000 columns.  Each INTO line has a projection and the sum of all those columns cannot exceed 1000.

Now your ibatis command will generate one INTO line for each entry in the list. 750 entries * 20 columns easily blows the 1000 column limit.  Hence the error.

How to fix it?

Well in Oracle we can use the TABLE() function to turn a nested table (list) into a data source like this:

```
insert into table_name
select * from table (some_list) ;
```

Normally I would expect a call like this to be wrapped in a stored procedure.  But either way, the list must fit a SQL Type (object) previously defined in the database.

So you  probably do not want to go down that route, because I guess you;'re using Ibatis specifically to avoid wrangling with databse objects.   But if you do decide to take that route you might find [this tutorial](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ibatis-user-java/200802.mbox/%3C15532303.post@talk.nabble.com%3E) helpful.

Otherwise, I fear you'll need to restrict the number of entries in your list to fifty.  You may think this is a bit of a pain, but really ibatis is not the right tool for doing bulk uploads.

Comment: thank you much!i would really appreciate if you could provide me some link from where I can gain more knowledge about 'really ibatis is not the right tool for doing bulk uploads' and what can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Multi Table Insert, which is not designed to insert record into one table. Use the following instead.

```
<insert id="someId" parameterType="someBean" >
    INSERT INTO table_name  (ID,NAME) VALUES
     <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" o >              
        ( #{item.id},#{item.name})
     </foreach>   
</insert>
```

Comment: thx 4 ur reply..but when i tried ur query which when used in oracle results into error : `SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: @pradeep upto some extent yes..but when we have used foreach,it means list may contains more than one values.so if the list contain a single value this query may work fine but not for multiple rows.Additionally there is no need for single-inverted comma as mybatis will automatically map the type of the object used as it is predefined in `someBean`.